# How to split a MultiProvider list of providers in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I have an app that starts with:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final initFuture = MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  final adState = AdState(initFuture);

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AdState>(create: (_) =>  adState),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SomeNotifier1()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SomeNotifier2()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SomeNotifier3()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SomeNotifier4()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SomeNotifier5()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SomeNotifier6()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SomeNotifier7()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SomeNotifier8()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SomeNotifier9()),
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SomeNotifier10())
      ],
      child: const MyApp()
    ),
  );
}
```

and for test reasons I would like to split the `providers` list in multiple lists like:

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final initFuture = MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  final adState = AdState(initFuture);

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AdState>(create: (_) =>  adState),
        ...list1(),
        ...list2()
      ],
      child: const MyApp()
    ),
  );
}

List<ChangeNotifierProvider<ChangeNotifier>> list1() =>
  [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SomeNotifier1()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SomeNotifier2()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SomeNotifier3()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SomeNotifier4()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SomeNotifier5())
  ];

List<ChangeNotifierProvider<ChangeNotifier>> list2() =>
  [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SomeNotifier6()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SomeNotifier7()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SomeNotifier8()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SomeNotifier9()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => SomeNotifier10())
  ];
```

> Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this
> Consumer Widget
>
> This happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include
> the provider of your choice. There are a few common scenarios: etc...

Is there any way to split the `MultiProvider` in multiple lists?

Also I am trying with something similar to:

```
return MultiProvider<Example>(
      create: (_) => Example(),
      builder: (context) {
        return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
      }
    ),
```

but no luck so far.

Comment: I normally get this sort of error when I forget to define the type, eg. `ChangeNotifierProvider<SomeNotifier1>()`. Did this work prior to splitting out the lists?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a BuildContext parameter to the function returning the providers like so

```
List<ChangeNotifierProvider<ChangeNotifier>> list1(BuildContext context) =>
  [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => SomeNotifier1()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => SomeNotifier2()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => SomeNotifier3()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => SomeNotifier4()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => SomeNotifier5())
  ];

List<ChangeNotifierProvider<ChangeNotifier>> list2(BuildContext context) =>
  [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => SomeNotifier6()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => SomeNotifier7()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => SomeNotifier8()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => SomeNotifier9()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (context) => SomeNotifier10())
  ];
```

then you can now add the providers like so

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final initFuture = MobileAds.instance.initialize();
  final adState = AdState(initFuture);

  runApp(
    MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        Provider<AdState>(create: (_) =>  adState),
        ...list1(context),
        ...list2(context)
      ],
      child: const MyApp()
    ),
  );
}
```

this should help.

Comment: I already tried that, but I could not find the `context` from the `main()` method.

Comment: it should work, just pass the context from there.